# search a keyword, if it matches pick the word besides to it

Tags: linux, sed, awk

```
255.255.0.0(queue=banglore)    
255.255.0.10(queue=hyderabad)    
255.255.1.2(cal = 10)
```

my Script is

```
command | awk '{print $3}' | sed '1,9d'
```

my output is nearly like as shown above in linux terminal..

by using awk and sed scripts i removed some useless matter. But, Now i want only the queue names with out the braces (i.e. only the words `banglore`, `hyderabad`). how to get that one.(using sed)
And that ip address will change rapidly.. 
thanks in advance ..

Comment: thnq -Steven Penny for the edit

Comment: You can combine the Awk and `sed` scripts to a single Awk script, trivially. Then add a `gsub` to replace before the opening paren and after the closing one.

Comment: if i use **gsub** i need to give another string for replace na.. but, just i want to get the queue name. that's it - @tripleee

Comment: Yes? Substitute the stuff before and after thr queue name with nothing, then print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -lne 'if(/queue=/){m/\(queue=(.*?)\)/g;print $1}' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
255.255.0.0(queue=banglore)    
255.255.0.10(queue=hyderabad)    
255.255.1.2(cal = 10) 
>
>
> perl -lne 'if(/queue=/){m/\(queue=(.*?)\)/g;print $1}' temp
banglore
hyderabad
>
```

Comment: wow.. that was excellent. But, it is printing cal value "10" also. I want the queue names only. Also it is printing queue names twice each one.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Updated so that it will print only queue values.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `grep` solution:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=queue=)[^)]*' file
banglore
hyderabad
```

Comment: thnq -sudo_O it was perfect

Answer (score 2):

awk version:

```
awk -F '\\(|\\)|=' '{if($3 !~/(^ )/)print $3}' temp
```

temp file:

```
255.255.0.0(queue=banglore)    
255.255.0.10(queue=hyderabad)    
255.255.1.2(cal = 10)
```

output:

```
banglore
hyderabad
```